# Get log data via TCP/IP

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I do logging debug info via serial port as usual. I would like to do the same via TCP. What are most popular libraries that solves this task?

Comment: I used ESPAsync check it out.

Comment: https://github.com/jandrassy/TelnetStream